# How to mold procedural python code to async python code?

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

So I have a procedural, synchronous python application. However due to a change of requirements, I also need to implement a client websocket listener to run in the background and listen to websocket events from a server while running the main application at the same time.

My team lead says to try to avoid threads and multiprocessing if I can. So I’m trying to implement the background listener with pythons asyncio module which runs on one thread. However, from my understanding, I would need to mold the whole application to run within an event loop?

I need to achieve cooperative multitasking somehow, since our main application code is not safe for random reentrancy. If we receive an websocket event, the current function of the main application should not be suspended somewhere in the middle of its execution, as it is the case in preemptive multitasking with threads. So our choice is either mold the entire application around an event-loop, or use multiprocessing, which then in return introduces other risks like dirty reads, lost updates or deadlocks.

Ideally, I would run everything in one thread, and if the websocket listener receives something, the context switch happens at the end of the current function call, not somewhere randomly. Is there a way to implement this easily in python?

I would be very grateful for help, thanks!

Comment: The scenario you describe is ideal for multoi-threading, actually. Not any number of arbitrary threads - just do the websocket part in a separate thread. And use asyncio on this websocket-site of the code if needed, with minimal, or no changes at all in the existing code.  "random re-entrancy" won't take place if you don't place calls directly in the server-side to the existing code: manage whatver tasks are necessary in the existing code with a queue.

Comment: other than the comment above, do not expect a full, working answer here, since you did not post any code. Preferably come down to a minimal skeleton example of what you have, along with some ideas of what you are trying to achieve - then people will be able to help yoiu.

Comment: @jsbueno thank you so much for your help! I was more looking for guidance how to even start. Now I know that asyncio is not the right approach. I'll use your guidance, and if I stumble on problems, maybe make a new post with example code. Cheers!